# Using RSpec to test an action class that instantiates a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm using an action/service based architecture where a service class hosts HTTP calls and action classes sanitize/package data and call the service class to talk to an outside API. The setup works fine, but I'm wondering how to set up mocks for the action classes. Here's an example action/service pair:

```
# Service
class UserService
  def update_user user_id, data
    # make request
  end
end

# Action
class UserUpdate
  def initialize user_id, user_data
    @id = user_id
    @sanitized_data = user_data
  end

  def call
    service = UserService.new
    service.call(@id, @sanitized_data)
  end
end
```

I can mock the action without issue, but when I try to use a class or instance double for the service, I get errors. Here's my test so far:

```
it "should create an instance of Agent Service" do
  agent_action_mock = class_double("AgentUpdate")
  agent_service_mock = class_double("AgentService")

  allow(agent_update_mock).to receive_message_chain(:new, :call)
  allow_any_instance_of(AgentService).to receive_message_chain(:initialize, :update_user)

  agenta_action_mock.new(99, { status: "Verified" }).call
  expect_any_instance_of(AgentService).to receive(:initialize)
end
```

Which nets me `Failure/Error: DEFAULT_FAILURE_NOTIFIER = lambda { |failure, _opts| raise failure } Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: initialize`

What I'm wondering is how can I test that the action is creating an instance of the service class and calling it's methods?

Comment: But are you sure it's really being called?

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with your test.
First, you are calling methods on a mock. Unless you setup a method to `call_original`, all the methods of the double are stubbed and do nothing. So there is no way calling the double's method to trigger the actual behavior.

Second, since you are using expectation at the end of the test, you should use the spy form of the expectation - `have_received`. Otherwise it looks for a call of :initialize after the expectation have been set, which never happens.